# Can't use a new provider in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to use `Laravel Searchy` [github here](https://github.com/TomLingham/Laravel-Searchy) in my `RegisterController.php` using `Laravel 5.4`
I followed this :

---

Add the service provider to the providers array in Laravel's `./config/app.php` file:

`TomLingham\Searchy\SearchyServiceProvider::class`

Add the Alias to the aliases array in Laravel's `./config/app.php` file if you want to have quick access to it in your application:

`'Searchy' => TomLingham\Searchy\Facades\Searchy::class`

---

## Problem

`Class searchy does not exist`

## RegisterController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Searchy;

class RegisterController extends Controller { 
    public function example () {
        Searchy::search('companies')->fields('name')->query('test')->getQuery()->limit(1)->get();
    }   
}
```

## Question

What should I do to be able to use it ?

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish  do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add This In Top of Your File**

```
use TomLingham\Searchy\SearchBuilder;
```

OR

**Try This In Composer**

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Comment: there is any config/searchy.php file exist in config folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144200/discussion-between-rishikesh-kumar-and-leo).